# keytool is not recognized as a command when trying to obtain key

Tags: android, cmd, keystore, android-keystore

I am setting up a google maps activity and I am trying to get my API key. However in my cmd I get the error that keytool is not recognized as an internal or external command....ect.... I tried using the solution posted in a similar question but it didn't work for me.

My Default dubug keystore

```
C:\Users\Sam\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your `%PATH%` - OS environment variable is not configured properly.

You can either:

> Call keytool by specifying full path to your `<Java_Home>/bin/keytool.exe` executable file.
> For me, the path looks like this:
> `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\keytool.exe"`

Or,

> Correct your `%Path%` variable; by appending `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to it.

Comment: how do i find mine then? I found what is above by going in to the properties in eclipse

Comment: look in the folder where you've installed Java

Comment: I tried but it says now when I use CMD that The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \ -keystore <C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>.keystore \ -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: position yourself in .android folder and execute this:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v

Comment: I used that in cmd because I'm not sure what you mean by positioning myself in the android folder. But when I ran it in cmd I got a java.lang.exception

Comment: do you even know how to navigate through your filesystem via cmd?

"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Sam\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -v

Answer (score 5):

```
"c:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\EIS\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Then hit the "Enter" key and your MD5 and SHA1 will show.